# Как реализовать группировку элементов в выпадающем списке ObjectSelect 'optgroup_identifier'

Tags: doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Подскажите как можно реализовать группировку элементов в выпадающем списке ObjectSelect '***optgroup_identifier***' (группирует по полю в таблице [Пример](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md#example-6-implementing--support))

`Form\CategoryForm.php`

```
$this->add([
    'type'  => ObjectSelect::class,
    'name' => 'category',
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'Категория',
        'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
        'target_class'   => Category::class,
        'property'       => 'name',
        'optgroup_identifier' => '???',
        'optgroup_default'    => 'Главная',
        'empty_option'   => '== Категория ==',
        'is_method'      => true,
        'find_method'    => [
            'name'   => 'findAllChildCategories',
            'params' => [

            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

Таблица категорий имеет отношение [Self-referencing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing)

`Entity\Category.php`

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $parent;
```

Названиями групп должны послужить родительские категории

`$category->getParent()->getName()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте дополнительную функцию в `Entity\Category` специально для взятия имени от `$this->parent`. Имя функции не должно совпадать ни с какими другими полями, чтобы `Doctrine` не пыталась вставить целый прокси объект в форму.

Например:

```
public function getParentName() {
    if(!$this->parent) return '';
        return $this->parent->getName();
}
```

Вставьте это имя в `optgroup_identifier`. `Doctrine` особенно магически ни чего не делает, просто зовёт геттер под этим именем, а значит он может быть чем угодно.

Сама функция проверяет наличия `parent` на случай, если корневая категория. Если да, верните пустой текст. Результат как на картинке. Это так, как нужно?

[image: результат]

Comment: Все работает изумительно!!!
Спасибо большое! Вы гений ))